# Why "foo = new double[int x, int y]" is legal but not "foo = new double[int x][int y]"?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I know there are differences between jagged and multidimensional arrays. I know it is often likeable to use a "List<>" instead of arrays of arrays.

Could someone just explain me why, in the following code, the first is allowed but the second is an error? I just want to better understand C#...

Legal:

```
public class Banana
{
    double[,] _banana;
    public Banana(int h, int w)
    {
        _banana= new double[h,w];
    }               
}
```

Illegal (Error: a constant value is expected instead of h and w):

```
public class Banana
{
    double[][] _banana;
    public Banana(int h, int w)
    {
        _banana= new double[h][w]{};
    }               
}
```

**TL;DR;**

Why is it possible to initialize the dimensions of a multi array with variables but not a jagged array's?

Comment: It's not a jagged array if you're initializing the length of both dimensions right away.

Comment: The designers of C# didn't feel that allowing this kind of initializer would be a useful enough feature to include it in the language. If you want all elements of the array to be the same width, use a 2D array; if you want them to possibly be different, you need to allocate them yourself.

Comment: Because the rules say so. You can do it in java (which lacks the first syntax) - it's not some sort of inherent impossibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `int[4,5]` is single object which holds twenty integers.  An `int[4][]` is an object which holds four references to integer arrays.  Having `int[][] foo = new int[4][5];` be equivalent to:

```
int[][] foo = new int[4][];
for (int temp = 0; temp < 4; temp++)
  foo[i] = new int[5];
```

would make about as much sense as having `StringBuilder bar[] = new StringBuilder[4]();` be equivalent to:

```
StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder[4];
for (int temp = 0; temp < 4; temp++)
  bar[i] = new StringBuilder();
```

Such a feature might be helpful in many cases, and there wouldn't be anything particularly wrong with it conceptually, but the code required to explicitly initialize array elements isn't particularly onerous, and writing such code explicitly helps make clear that the array-of-references and the things to which those references refers are all separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

With a jagged array you have to initialize each "leg" separately - there's no syntax to initialize the size of each leg in one pass:

```
public Banana(int h, int w)
{
    _banana = new double[h][];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        _banana[i] = new double[w];
    }
}
```

Why is there no syntax? Because the spec doesn't require it, and in a "typical" jagged array the legs have different lengths, otherwise a 2-D array may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Not enough rep yet to upvote but it was useful to my understanding!

Answer (score 0):

Each nested array in a jagged array can have a different length. If you had to initialize it using your syntax example, they would all be required to have the same length. It simply doesn't make sense. You'd have to use something like:

```
_banana = new double[h][];
for(var i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    _banana[h] = new double[w];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was useful to my understanding too, but I havn't enough rep yet to upvote!